# Can I transfer a function to the "onclick" event with the notation?

Tags: html, css, typescript

```
  updateUI() {
    const itemsContainer = document.getElementById("items") as HTMLDivElement;
    if (!itemsContainer) return;

    itemsContainer.innerHTML = "";

    this.items.forEach((item: Item) => {
      const itemElement = document.createElement("div") as HTMLDivElement;
      itemElement.className = "item";
      itemElement.innerHTML = `
        <div class="item-name">${item.name}</div>
         <button class="item-button" onclick="inventory.removeItem(${item.id})">Remove</button>
      `;
      itemsContainer.appendChild(itemElement);
    });
  }
```

I just wanted to create a button with the notation that calls the removeItem() function with a click so that the created item is then deleted by ID.

As soon as I press my remove button I get this error:

"
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
inventory is not defined
ReferenceError: inventory is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://localhost:8080/:66:2)
"

I thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Yes? `inventory` is not defined is what the error is, and there is no definition of the variable `inventory` in your provided code. So how should we know what you meant when you wrote `inventory.removeItem()`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Make `inventory` global:

```
globalThis.inventory = inventory;
```

2. Add `onclick` from JS:

```
itemElement.querySelector('.item-button').onclick = () => inventory.removeItem(item.id)
```